# Data import tool for Salesforce

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, salesforce-lightning

I want to do some research into a legitimate way to get data into Salesforce. It needs to be able to read data from a spreadsheet and then determine what action to take record by record. A given input record might result in an account, a contact, and an opportunity based on business rules. It also needs to be able to do lookups for any duplicates first and then determine what action to take record by record. It needs to be repeatable. We have data that they want to import from external systems monthly.

Is there a recommended tool for importing row data into several objects such as Account, Contact and Opportunity?  One that can be used with SSIS wouldn't hurt

Comment: google it. there are third party tools which can be integrated with SSIS for SalesForce connection. Stack overflow doesn't encourage suggesting tools or books.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. Unfortunately I have not found a 3rd party tool that accomplishes my requirement

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce.com has multiple ways to import/export data. As Prbhat G suggested, a quick google search will yield a variety of 3rd party tools to directly connect to the Salesforce.com universe. An example would be ZappySys or CozyRoc. Without a 3rd party tool, you'll have a web services option (offered by Salesforce.com) (https://www.blendo.co/blog/load-data-from-salesforce-to-sql-data-warehouse/) and common, but less desirable options, such as importing/exporting from EXCEL spreadsheets or files. Whatever your choice outside of a web service, you'll need a reliable Salesforce.com ODBC driver. Here is one that Salesforce offers for its CRM product as an example. (https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008nLjIAI).

Answer (score 0):

In general, what you are talking about is an ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) process from your spreadsheet(s) and into Salesforce. Depending on the scale you are looking to work with, there are many different ways to accomplish this. I'll give some different points on that spectrum.

**Script**

Every so often (via cron), you could run a script in the language of your choosing that does this. For example, if you know how to write Node.js code, you could use that. There are libraries for [Google Sheets](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet) and [Salesforce](https://jsforce.github.io/). You'd connect to your Sheets, read the code into memory or save it somewhere, then process it by sending it to the appropriate place in Salesforce. Of course, there are credentials needed to get access to those things.

**Tool**

There are tools that can be made to accomplish your use cases. For example, a Reverse ETL tool like [Grouparoo](https://www.grouparoo.com) can read your sheets, normalize the data, and send it various destinations such as Salesforce. Using a tool would  result in a more predictable behavior and more efficiency. For example, it would be set up to not update Salesforce with records that it had already told them about. Or it could handle more rows than would fit into memory.

**Pipeline**

Depending on the scale and number of sheets and the processing that needs to be done, you might want to use a tool like [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) to coordinate many concurrent jobs, update a database or warehouse, and then process them in some way before using a Reverse ETL to write them to Salesforce.